# Restricting CPU time of processes by executable path

Tags: linux, process, users, limit, cpu-usage

Is there a way to restrict CPU time (duration) for all processes which are invoked by executables that are located in a certain directory?

I would like to be able to auto-kill all applications which certain users start in their home directories after a certain amount of time (for example after 10 minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running) and this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage)

The only thing I'll add is the `-u` user option for `ps` eg:

```
ps -u <username>
```

to search processes started by a user.